# What is the difference between the two Casts for a Dynamic Object in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

Number one works, but number 2 causes a compile error, I am trying to understand why?
`people` is an `ExpandoObject`

```
 dynamic result2 = (people as List<dynamic>).Where(p => p.firstname == "name");
 dynamic result = people.Cast<List<dynamic>>().Where(p => p.firstname == "name");
```

I am getting the following compile error with the second syntax in the `Where` expression:

> cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically
>   dispatched operation without first  casting it to a delegate or
>   expression tree type.

Comment: IIRC, The first casts the list while the second casts the items of the list.

Comment: @ATC thank you very much. Now I understand

Comment: @Nkosi thanks a lot for the explanation

Comment: @user3726459 the initial explanations given are incorrect. `people` is a dynamic object so that means that the `Cast` being called is also dynamic. And so on and so on. `people` needs to be cast to a proper type first before lambda expressions will work. Like in the first statement.